# Reading a fixed width float from char string with sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

Is it possible to use `sscanf` to read the char string `s` in the example below as two 10-chars (including the blank space) wide floats? Or do I have to copy chunks of 10 chars to a temporary char array and use `sscanf` on that temp array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
   char s[]={"     6.4887.0522e+06"};
   float f1, f2;

   sscanf(s, "%10f%10f", &f1, &f2);
   printf("%10f %10f\n", f1, f2);
}
```

My wish in this example is to get `f1 = 6.448` and `f2 = 7052200.` from the `sscanf` read.

Comment: If we assume that this is just an example and you want to have a general algorithm for parsing such data, then the answer depends on what can be taken as constants in the data format. (E.g. are the groups of digits after the dots always 4 long?). Generally you can juggle with field widths to stop in the middle of a number, but as @user3121023 said, whitespace does not count.

Comment: Thanks, but I was obviously not clear enough. The char array should always be parsed as groups of 10 chars long. So the first sub string in my example is "     6.488" and the second is "7.0522e+06". The problem is not reading this particular string only. I am looking for a general way to read this kind of data where each 10-char sub string can contain any kind of floating point value formatted on a valid floating point format.

Comment: you can split the array: https://ideone.com/CGgtUj

Comment: Yeah, that's the copy to temp array solution, although I think tmp[10] = 0; should be set before calling sscanf, right? I was more looking for a way to make sscanf to _not_ discard the leading blank space characters by using some bracket format rule, convert the sub string to a float and set it to the following char pointer. But maybe that it is not possible.

Comment: True about " tmp[10] = 0; should be set before calling sscanf,".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scanset might work. Put the valid characters in the brackets. The 10 limits the scan to 10 characters. The `%n` specifier will report the number of characters processed by the scan. That can be used in the sscanf to iterate through a long string.

```
char substr[11] = {'\0'};
char s[]={"     6.4887.0522e+06"};
int offset = 0;
int used = 0;

while ( ( sscanf ( s + offset, "%10[-+.eE 0-9]%n", substr, &used)) == 1) {
    if ( used == 10) {
        printf ( "%s\n", substr);
        //convert as needed
        offset += used;
    }
    else {
        //do something to handle the problem
        break;//one option...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's some pretty nifty usage of the sscanf format. I accept this as an answer and thank you for the time spent on my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If `s[]` is not `const`, temporarily make `s[10] = 0`.

```
void foo(char *s) {
  while (*s) {
    size_t length = strlen(s);
    char temp = 0;
    if (length > 10) {
      length = 10;
      temp = s[10];
      s[10] = 0;
    } 
    float f1;
    if (sscanf(s, "%f", &f1) == 1) printf("%f\n", f1);
    s += length;
    s[0] = temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is also a good answer. I am a little bit surprised though that there is no option to make sscanf to include the leading blank space in the maximum field width parameter. I can not see how discarding the leading blanks would be more useful than to _not_ discard them. If these blank space were included, reading fixed field width data format would be a one-liner.

Comment: @Anders `scanf()` is design more for data where the amount of white-space is irrelevant.  IAC, simple copying the 10 `char` into a buffer, appending a null character and then parsing seems simple enough.